# Tensorflow Conditional Graph Construction

Tags: tensorflow

To vary the Tensorflow graph at construction time (not dynamically while running the graph) I use conditional branching such as the following. Is this the correct way of doing this with Tensorflow?

```
with tf.Graph().as_default()`:
  ...
  if a > 1:
    weightsLayer1 = tf.Variable(tf.truncated_normal([x1,y1])
  else:
    weightsLayer1 = tf.Variable(tf.random_normal([x2,y2])
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, you use regular `if`s, their value will be evaluated during python runtime, so in the graph construction time, and depending on the value then, your `weightsLayer1` will get this value or another.

To do conditional graph construction during graph execution, you can use [tf.cond](https://www.tensorflow.org/versions/r0.11/api_docs/python/control_flow_ops.html#cond). You use it like this:

```
weightLayer1 = tf.cond(a > 1, lambda: tf.Variable(tf.truncated_normal([x1,y1])), 
                              lambda: tf.Variable(tf.random_normal([x2,y2])))
```

Answer (score 1):

Yes it is correct. Note that only one of the branch will be added to the graph. If you want to vary at runtime you can use `tf.cond` or `tf.select`.